# Diffrence between Triggers, Behaviors and Commands in MVVM?

Tags: silverlight, mvvm

Can anyone please explain difference between Triggers, Behaviors and Commands. I tried to search on this, but could not find anything useful.

And would also like to know in which scenario which one should be preferred and which one is used frequently among them?

Answer (score 1):

**Behavior** is a way of interactivity without writing code. Behaviors makes interactivity much simpler for the designers. In short, a behavior is a reusable piece that encapsulates some functionality that can be attached to an object to extend its built-in interactivity capabilities.

**Commands** are used to encapsulate a piece of logic, which various Silverlight controls can bind to and execute in response to an event, such as a button being clicked. You can expose a command from a ViewModel as a property and bind the Command property of a control in the View to it. When the control is clicked, the command will be executed.

In **MVVM** scenarios, **triggers** are used to notifying the view of an event from a ViewModel.

For example, perhaps the view needs to navigate to another view once a save operation is
complete. You can implement this behavior by raising an event from the ViewModel that the view can listen for by doing either of the following:

• Wiring up an event handler in the view’s code-behind and writing some code to
respond to the event (Not recommended approach)

• Implementing a **trigger** in the view that listens for the event and responds accordingly

You can see [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/deviations/archive/2009/06/06/my-first-silverlight-behavior.aspx), [this](http://www.silverlightshow.net/items/Behaviors-and-Triggers-in-Silverlight-3.aspx) and [this](http://www.dotnetcurry.com/showarticle.aspx?ID=671) for more explanations.

Also, [Pro Business Applications with Silverlight 5](http://www.apress.com/9781430235002) is a very good reference for you.